# Quadratic equation class in Python OOP

Tags: python, object-oriented

**Hello everyone**

In today's assignment I had to write a function to determine if (and how many) the quadratic function defined by the formula f(x) = ax^2 + bx +c has roots. I had decorators to write.

Here is my solution:

```
from typing import List, Tuple
from math import sqrt
from datetime import datetime

class DeltaError(Exception):
    '''Error when calculating roots, and delta is lower than 0.'''
    def __init__(self):
        Exception.__init__(self, "Delta must be greater than 0!")

class Quadratic:
    
    def __init__(self, a: int, b: int, c: int):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.x = -1

       
    @property
    def Roots(self):
        a, b, c = self.a, self.b, self.c
        d = sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)
        if d > 0:
            x1 = (-b + d) / (2 * a)
            x2 = (-b - d) / (2 * a)
            return x1, x2
        if d == 0:
            return -b / 2 * a
        if d < 0:
            raise ZeroError
        
    @property
    def Vietas_formula(self):
        a, b, c = self.a, self.b, self.c
        d = b * b - 4 * a * c
        if d > 0:
            return "x1 + x2 = {x}".format(x = -b / a), "x1 * x2 = {y}".format(y = c / a)

    @property
    def Vertex(self):
        a, b, c = self.a, self.b, self.c
        d = b * b - 4 * a * c
        return "W: ({p}, {q})".format(p = -b / 2 * a, q = -d / 4 * a)

    @property
    def Time_dependent(self):
        if datetime.now().hour + 2 in range(8, 16):
            return "Roots"
        else: return "Break"

    @property
    def x_plus_3(self):
        a, b, c, x = self.a, self.b, self.c, self.x
        x += 3
        return x * (x * a + b) + c

    



quad = Quadratic(1, 5, 6)
print(quad.Roots, quad.Vietas_formula, quad.Vertex, quad.Time_dependent, quad.x_plus_3)
```

I'm counting on advice, and a better use of classes, static assignment to a, b, c and delta values, so that through inheritance I can use in subsequent functions without having to declare them from scratch.

**Have a nice day!**

Comment: _[you] had decorations to write_ as in the assignment forces you to call into declarations like `@property`?

Comment: ummm... probably im wrong, but i thought @property are parts of decorators, but as i said im probably wrong.... How should I use decorators there?

Comment: No you're right - `@property` is a decorator; your wording just befuddled me a little.

Comment: And actually your use of `@property` overall is quite good, all things considered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some minor stuff -

- your member functions and properties should be lower-case by PEP8
- you should add a property to get the discriminant, particularly since you use it in multiple places
- I don't know what `time_dependent` and `x_plus_3` do, nor why they're here. They seem like specific applications of the quadratic formula for a narrow situation. Given that, they should not be in this class.
- The returns from `vietas_formula` should not be strings; you should return a tuple of floats. Similar for `vertex`. Currently this is premature stringizing. Your `roots` already does this correctly.
- If you wanted to be thorough, `d < 0` should not raise a `ZeroError` and instead should return complex roots. Python has [built-in support for complex numbers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html).
- `self.x` does not belong as a member on the class.
- Have you renamed `DeltaError` to `ZeroError`?
- `Exception.__init__` should be changed to use `super()`
- The error message `Delta must be greater than 0!` is not strictly true, and should be `greater than or equal to zero`.
- Why must `a, b, c` be `int`? You should accept `float`.

Some major stuff: have you checked this for correctness? I see at least three algebraic errors, including that `d = sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)` is calling `sqrt` too early to catch failures, and `-b / 2 * a` has incorrect order of operations. Unit testing for this kind of code is both easy and important; while translating your code I ran into test failures and had to make corrections almost every step of the way.

### Suggested

I still don't understand why your code needs to take a break (it's actually pretty funny. Maybe it's unionized?), but so be it:

```
from cmath import sqrt, isclose
from datetime import datetime, time
from numbers import Complex
from typing import Union, Tuple

RootTypes = Union[
    Tuple[Complex],
    Tuple[Complex, Complex],
]

WORK_HOURS_START = time(8)
WORK_HOURS_END = time(16)


class Quadratic:
    def __init__(self, a: float, b: float, c: float):
        self.a, self.b, self.c = a, b, c

    def y(self, x: Complex) -> Complex:
        a, b, c = self.a, self.b, self.c
        return a*x*x + b*x + c

    def dydx(self, x: Complex) -> Complex:
        a, b = self.a, self.b
        return 2*a*x + b

    @property
    def discriminant(self) -> float:
        a, b, c = self.a, self.b, self.c
        return b*b - 4*a*c

    @property
    def roots(self) -> RootTypes:
        a, b, c, d = self.a, self.b, self.c, self.discriminant
        if d == 0:
            return -b/2/a,

        sqrt_d = sqrt(d)
        return (-b + sqrt_d)/2/a, (-b - sqrt_d)/2/a

    @property
    def vietas_formula(self) -> Tuple[
        float,  # sum
        float,  # product
    ]:
        a, b, c = self.a, self.b, self.c
        return -b/a, c/a

    @property
    def vertex(self) -> Tuple[
        float,  # p
        float,  # q
    ]:
        a, b, c, d = self.a, self.b, self.c, self.discriminant
        return -b/a/2, -d/a/4

    def describe(self) -> str:
        v1, v2 = self.vietas_formula
        return (
            f'Roots: {self.roots}\n'
            f'Vieta constants: x1+x2={v1}, x1*x2={v2}\n'
            f'Vertex: {self.vertex}'
        )


def time_problem() -> None:
    if WORK_HOURS_START <= datetime.now().time() < WORK_HOURS_END:
        a, b, c = 1, 5, 6
        quad = Quadratic(a, b, c)
        print(quad.describe())
    else:
        print("I'm on a break for some reason.")


def abs_close(x: Complex, y: Complex) -> bool:
    return isclose(x, y, abs_tol=1e-12)


def test_two_real() -> None:
    q = Quadratic(1, 5, 6)

    x1, x2 = q.roots
    assert abs_close(0, x1.imag)
    assert abs_close(0, x2.imag)
    assert abs_close(0, q.y(x1))
    assert abs_close(0, q.y(x2))

    v1, v2 = q.vietas_formula
    assert abs_close(v1, x1 + x2)
    assert abs_close(v2, x1 * x2)

    vx, vy = q.vertex
    assert abs_close(0, q.dydx(vx))
    assert abs_close(vy, q.y(vx))


def test_one_real() -> None:
    q = Quadratic(9, -6, 1)

    x, = q.roots
    assert abs_close(0, x.imag)
    assert abs_close(0, q.y(x))

    # In this case Vieta's formula can be interpreted as two identical superimposed roots
    x1, x2 = x, x
    v1, v2 = q.vietas_formula
    assert abs_close(v1, x1 + x2)
    assert abs_close(v2, x1 * x2)

    vx, vy = q.vertex
    assert abs_close(0, q.dydx(vx))
    assert abs_close(0, vy)


def test_two_complex() -> None:
    q = Quadratic(4, -4, 3)

    x1, x2 = q.roots
    assert not abs_close(0, x1.imag)
    assert not abs_close(0, x2.imag)
    assert abs_close(0, q.y(x1))
    assert abs_close(0, q.y(x2))

    v1, v2 = q.vietas_formula
    assert abs_close(v1, x1 + x2)
    assert abs_close(v2, x1 * x2)

    vx, vy = q.vertex
    assert abs_close(0, q.dydx(vx))
    assert abs_close(vy, q.y(vx))


def test() -> None:
    test_two_real()
    test_one_real()
    test_two_complex()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
    time_problem()
```

Comment: time dependence is quite simple, when the current time is between 8am and 3pm it should return roots, otherwise it should return "im having a break"

Comment: That's weird, but sure. There's a better way to go about comparing a time range.